# Download progress notification and Google Play Store showing different progress percentage

Tags: google-play-store, download-manager

As the title says, I've noticed that the download progress in the notification bar and the progress in the Play Store shows different progresses. Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

My question is **why does this happen?** Is this a bug?

Also, when the download progress in the notification bar reaches 100%, the progress in the Play Store jumps to 100% and the app I'm updating gets updated.

Comment: While it probably wouldn't be an issue in using Play Store or the device, I  find it pretty annoying.

Comment: @Firelord and OP(Cool guy) : occasionally,  possibly due to the lag of displaying a progress bar (a little test I done proved this)  the play store one can be slower than the notification bar. That being said,  it always catches up at 100%, for obvious reasons.

Comment: I guess the progress bar would be the same on both but since your swipe down the notification the progress bar in the actuall app is not correctly reflected. See what happens if you click the notification while the app is downloading and check if the both the percentage values are same?

Comment: @Lucky No change even after clicking the notification. Seems like the accepted answer is correct (See [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Google-Play-Store-show-two-different-downloaded-statuses-in-app-and-in-notification))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure that this is based on the fact that updates aren't loaded fully but in parts. The notification bar then shows the progress only for what is really being downloaded, the Play Store itself shows the progress for the entire app.

Comment: [Discussion about this on quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Google-Play-Store-show-two-different-downloaded-statuses-in-app-and-in-notification)

Answer (score 0):

You could try wiping the data of the play store. It happened to me on my Galaxy S2, which ran CM. Wiping the data of the app did the trick for my phone, could work for your device.